# Decent Exposure undefined method `attributes=' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am starting to use decent_exposure in my rails apps and am having a problem when trying to update a record. I get:

```
NoMethodError in Frontend::UsersController#update
undefined method `attributes=' for nil:NilClass
Around line 22:
def update
  if user.save (line 22)
    redirect_to user_path(user.username)
  else
    render :edit
```

My controller:

```
class Frontend::UsersController < Frontend::FrontendController
  expose(:user, finder: :find_by_username, finder_parameter: :username, attributes: :user_params)

def create
  if user.save
    redirect_to user_path(user.username)
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def update
  if user.save
    redirect_to user_path(user.username)
  else
    render :edit
  end
end

private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :username, :birthday)
  end
end
```

My FrontentController really only `< ApplicationController` for now.

And in app controller:

```
decent_configuration do
  strategy DecentExposure::StrongParametersStrategy
end
```

So I have done all that the decent_exposure gem requires, saving a user in the create method causes no issues. If I change `save` to `update` I again get the same error. Any idea why it's not picking up my user_params from the expose method call?

**Edit**

I've added my view partial:

```
= form_for user do |f|
  - if user.errors.any?
    %ul
      = list_of user.errors.full_messages do |error|
        = error.humanize
  %div
    %p= f.label :firstname
    %p= f.text_field :firstname
  %div
    %p= f.label :lastname
    %p= f.text_field :lastname
  %div
    %p= f.label :email
    %p= f.text_field :email
  %div
    %p= f.label :username
    %p= f.text_field :username
  %div
    %p= f.label :birthday
    %p= f.text_field :birthday
  %div= f.submit
```

Having dug around a bit more, it seems that the action for editing is `update/:id` rather than `update/:username`. I can get around this in the edit form (if I take it out of a partial) by passing the url as `user_path(user.username)`. That leads me to another question: if I were using the instance variable `@user` I could do `form_for @user do |f|...` and it would pick the correct route for me, but I have to explicitly pass `user.username` as an argument to the `user_path` route generator using decent_exposure. Why is this? Or have I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it turns out that using decent_exposure doesn't alter the requirement to override `to_param` for the model in question. So a quick:

```
def to_param
  username
end
```

in user.rb and all is well. Lesson learnt!